# How does malloc distinguish between me allocating a long long integer and an array of two integers?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, allocation

in my OS long long int is : 8 bytes .
int is 4 bytes .

```
int *p = malloc(4);
```

this code allocate 4 bytes for a variable of type integer on the heap .

```
int *p = malloc(8);
```

will this allocate a long long integer like 'one variable' or  two items on an array .

how can i allocate an integer of 8 bytes long ?
how can i allocate an array containing 2 items ?

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't know anything about the type of data, it just allocates memory.

Comment: `malloc()` does not care about data type sizes. It's up to you to do the math when allocating memory of size * your data type size.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc (first comment to the question and accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc()` just allocates raw memory, whether it's treated as an array or a single variable is determined by how the memory is used in the caller.

```
int *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

treats the memory as an array of 2 `int`. You can then do:

```
p[0] = 1;
p[1] = 2;
```

and it will write two `int` into the memory.

```
long int *p = malloc(sizeof(long int));
```

treats the memory as a single `long int` (or, equivalently, an array of 1 `long int`). Then you can do:

```
*p = 12345678;
```

and it will write that long integer into the memory.

Both of them will allocate 8 bytes of memory on a system where `int` is 4 bytes and `long int` is 8 bytes.

Comment: so i need to specify pointer type(long int *p=) so the program know that i want a long integer and not array of 2 integers

Comment: Yes. When you use `p` it uses its type to know how to interpret the memory it points to.

Comment: That's the reason why you have to specify the type of the pointer.

Comment: so what will happen if i do int *p=malloc(5)

Comment: The first 4 bytes of the allocation will be used when you dereference the pointer, the extra byte will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an 8 byte integer, it's called a `long long` or [`int64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)/[`int64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer):

If this is about C, then you use `malloc`:

```
int64_t* p = malloc(sizeof(int64_t));
```

If this is about C++, then you use `new`:

```
int64_t* p = new int64_t;
```

With your original code you're getting an allocation of *arbitrary size* mapped to a pointer of a *fixed size type*, where `int` is typically 4 bytes, or in other words, you have room for `int[2]`.

> Note: For portability reasons it's always best to express your allocations in terms of base types, not just abstract numbers. `malloc(8)` may allocate memory for 2 x `int`, or it may not, that depends on what `sizeof(int)` is. `malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)` always works correctly.